# Publish JAX-WS endpoint with embedded Jetty 7

Tags: java, jax-ws, embedded-jetty

Can anybody help with this?

I want to use an embedded Jetty 7 as Endpoint. This is what I tried:

```
public class MiniTestJetty {

@WebService(targetNamespace = "http")
public static class Calculator {

    @Resource
    WebServiceContext context;

    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int port = 8080;
    Server server = new Server(port);

    Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
    Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:" + port + "/calc", calculator);

    server.start();
    server.join();
}
```

}

But I cannot see whether this really uses Jetty instead of the default sun HttpServer.

One blog mentioned

```
 System.setProperty("com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServerProvider",
       "org.mortbay.jetty.j2se6.JettyHttpServerProvider");
```

But there doesn't seems to be such HttpServerProvider in Jetty 7.

Thanks for any help, Axel.

Comment: looks like there is code in the contrib section of Jetty 6 which does
something similar but nothing in Jetty 7

Answer (score 4):

All what is necessary seems to be

```
System.setProperty("com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServerProvider", "org.mortbay.jetty.j2se6.JettyHttpServerProvider");
```

The current contrib code from jetty-contrib/org/mortgay/jetty/j2se6 is not ready yet for Jetty 7. That's all.

Comment: How did you figure that out please ?

Answer (score 3):

You could simply open the URL of the WSDL in Firefox and check the response headers with Firebug. You should get something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Jetty(7.1.2.v20100523)
```

Answer (score 2):

The class was renamed to

```
org.eclipse.jetty.http.spi.JettyHttpServerProvider
```

And i took it from http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/updates/jetty-bundles-9.x/9.0.6.v20130930/:

V9.0.6 for Java 7
V9.3.2 is for Java 8