# Does http-kit support SOAP?

Tags: soap, clojure, axis, http-kit

I am considering to have a SOAP web service written using Apache Axis2. I can either use the Axis server or pack it as a .war and deploy it to a servlet container. My REST service is running on http-kit. Is it possible to to use http-kit with SOAP or does it support SOAP? Or should I need a separate servlet container like tomcat or Axis2? Thanks.

Update: Apache CXF instead of Axis2. I think I cannot use http-kit.

Comment: Can you tell us why you plan to use SOAP over the simpler REST?

Comment: It's for an RFC implementation. So I have to support SOAP for back channel communication.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to expose a SOAP-service.
I have a sample project which does that:

https://github.com/slipset/soap-box

It uses `javax.ws.rs-api` and runs as an uber-jar.

Comment: Yes, I need to provide a SOAP endpoint. So since soap-box uses JAX-WS, you start the service using `Endpoint`. So it will be a self serving server. Is it possible to use http-kit in some way. I suppose not, but I am not clear on this. Because currently we have some tooling that is specific for http-kit.

Comment: Could this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625666/publish-jax-ws-endpoint-with-embedded-jetty-7

Comment: Jetty does support hosting web service endpoint as well as http endpoint. Not sure about http-kit.